# problem YII2 session destroy is not working

Tags: session, yii2

i have a problem.
In Yii2 i have a view, controller, and layout.
in the layout and view, i check for the session if active do something.
the code is like this:

```
if (!isset($session)) $session = Yii::$app->session;
if ($session->isActive && $session->has('username')):
   //some code here if there is session echo something
else:
  //some code here if there is no session echo something else
endif;
```

then i have a controller action, which destroy session but also redirect to the view file above, the code is like this:

```
public function actionDestroysess($status = 1) {
        Yii::$app->session->destroy();
        return $this->render('masuk', ['status' => $status]);
}
```

the problem is, the session condition in view return true, it means that the `Yii::$app->session->destroy();` is not working at all, i tried to `var_dump(Yii::$app->session->get('username));` at the controller below the destroy command, but still get the value. Help me, why this session destroy is not working?

Comment: What `Yii::$app->session->isActive` returns if you call it before `Yii::$app->session->destroy()`?

Answer (score -1):

try this:
Change

```
Yii::$app->session->destroy();
```

to

```
Yii::$app->getSession()->destroy();
```

if you want to remove exact session you must use:

```
Yii::$app->session->remove('name')
```

Comment: `Yii::$app->session` or `Yii::$app->getSession()` are same without any difference. see the official [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-sessions-cookies#sessions)

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam getSession is a session component. see this [link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Application.php)

Comment: try to see the output of `print_r(Yii::$app->session);` and `print_r(Yii::$app->getSession());` to see what i am trying to tell. they both return `yii\web\Session` Object

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I say `try this` cause maybe the problem is in the method he used after that is said he can use `remove` method to do the job directly.